Translating manorial court rolls: is interesse a noun?
I am translating some 17th century manorial court rolls as light entertainment and keep coming across the word 'interesse'. I've found it translated as 'interest' (relating to a property transaction) in Janet Morris' glossary, but she does not specify what part of language it is eg noun,verb? It appears to be a noun in the example from the document below:
Ad hanc Curiam venit Gracia Snooke vidua et sursum
Reddidit in manus Domini totum jus titulum interesse et
demandam
If this is a noun, can anyone supply the nominative/genitive cases for me?
